# Configuring in-memory or embedded database to test production code

Tags: java

I have a requirement where in I have to test a DAO java class in production code using an in-memory database. The DAO performs insert operation using a different connection configuration.

I tried configuring hsql embedded database which comes with spring but looks like it needs programmatic configuration setup within the DAO production code for it to work but I cannot change the production code. Can someone suggest me a way to configure a embedded database to test my production DAO code through junits.

I tried this configuration:

```
@Before
public void setUp()
{
    db = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL).addScript("create-table.sql").addScript("insert-data.sql").build();
}
```

But this above code is in my junit. Without this above code I am not seeing a way to configure the in-memory database. I cannot have this code in my production environment. How can I configure the in-memory database without making changes to the production code.

Comment: it is not clear what you tried and what didn't work, but you can have a different spring context for your unit tests and that would probably solve your problem.

Comment: I updated the question with the configuration I tried.

Answer (score 0):

I created a TestConfig as my spring configuration file for my junits, and configured two beans in there:

1. EmbeddedDatabase bean to return the embedded database.

   ```
   @Bean
   @Profile("test-profile")
   public EmbeddedDatabase embeddedDatabase()
   {
       return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setName("Derby").setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.DERBY).addScript("schema.sql").build();
   }
   ```
2. Then a bean for getting the Connection out of the above created database.

   ```
   @Bean
   @Profile("test-profile")
   public Connection connection() throws SQLException
   {
       return embeddedDatabase().getConnection();
   }
   ```

   My production code gets the Connection object from spring's ApplicationContext. So I configured my junits to run using my TestConfig so the production code pulled in the embedded database connection object and passed it along. The tests passed.